# maven-soapui-pro-plugin: parameterize WSDl location

Tags: java, maven, wsdl, soapui

I am trying to start an embbeded soapui mock webservice using the maven-soapui-pro-plugin plugin.
This works perfectly on my local machine but will obviously crash on the continuous integration plateforme as the project file references a wsdl on the local filesystem.
Therefore I have four options:
1/ Find a way to pass the wsdl file location as a parameter.
2/ Change this reference to an HTTP (which means I have to install an Apache server)
3/ Manualy change the references to the wsdl in the project file.
4/ Replace that plugin by an other one

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>eviware</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-soapui-pro-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.0</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                    <version>5.1.6</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>    
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>mock</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <projectFile>D:\Documents and Settings\jhagai\Bureau\Toto-soapui-project.xml</projectFile>
                        <mockService>MockService</mockService>
                        <port>8888</port>
                        <path>/test</path>
                        <noBlock>true</noBlock>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I feel like I am the only person facing this issue is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

First off you don't actually need the wsdl file on the CI server.  There are several tests in on our CI server that do not point to a wsdl file.  SoapUI uses the wsdl file to generate the project and sample requests, but if you run the test without it and your test is configured properly, it shouldn't fail.  We have implemented number 2 that you have listed, but this is so testers don't need to generate the wsdls themselves.

The problem I see above is the hard coded project file.  You should be able to handle this by saving your project in your maven project and pointing to it there (map to it based on the location of the POM).